# adding jquery in Jhipster angular project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jhipster

I am new in Jhipster and Angular, and I am struggling in adding a jquery instance in my Jhipster Angular project.

I simply need to change the theme and outlook of the default jhipster application. For that purpose I downloaded a theme which has the combination of jquery and bootstrap, therefore, I installed the jquery through npm in the jhipster project.

I can see its folder in the node_modules as well, so it is already available.

Even though I have added its link in the vendor.ts but it seems it does not get loaded. So here my vendor.ts code where I am importing jquery file

```
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
```

To test my jquery object I coded following in my home.component.ts file.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModalRef } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { JhiEventManager } from 'ng-jhipster';
import { LoginModalService, AccountService, Account } from 'app/core';

declare var $: any;
@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['home.css'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    account: Account;
    modalRef: NgbModalRef;

    constructor(
        private accountService: AccountService,
        private loginModalService: LoginModalService,
        private eventManager: JhiEventManager
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {

        alert('I am Called');

        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert('I am Called From jQuery');
        });


    }
```

But it gives me an error after the page gets loaded

```
ERROR ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at HomeComponent.ngOnInit
```

Any tip on this matter would be highly appreciable.

EDIT: I am adding my angular.json code

```
{

"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
"version": 1,
"newProjectRoot": "projects",
"projects": {
    "paperproject": {
        "root": "",
        "sourceRoot": "src/main/webapp",
        "projectType": "application",
        "architect": {}
    }

},
"defaultProject": "paper-auth",
"cli": {
    "packageManager": "npm"
},
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
        "inlineStyle": true,
        "inlineTemplate": false,
        "spec": false,
        "prefix": "jhi",
        "styleExt": "css"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
        "spec": false,
        "prefix": "jhi"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:guard": {
        "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
        "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:service": {
        "spec": false
    },
    "scripts": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
}
}
```

It didn't had any script attribute therefore I added script attribute But it still does not work. Jhipster wizard only creates this default angular.json file.
 I added

> ```
>   "scripts": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
> ```

Comment: afiak `ngOnInit` isn't really compatible with `doc.ready`.

Comment: doc.ready works fine when I add     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
in the index.html file.  But adding hard coded js library is not what I am looking.

Comment: Also it is just to test if jquery works or not, this is the only purpose why I added alert inside doc.ready.

Comment: Two proposed solutions are not complete and will not work because they don't take JHipster into account : angular.json is not read by JHipster, same thing for index.html. Have you read your project's README.md? It provides an example on how to integrate an external JS dependecy. In addition you should configure webpack.ProvidePlugin see https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#usage-jquery

Answer (score 1):

try this:

> npm i jquery --save

in TypeScript file:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

ngOnInit() {

    alert('I am Called');

    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('I am Called From jQuery');
    });

}
```

---

or

add jquery script in index.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

on TypeScript file:

```
declare var $: any;


ngOnInit() {
  alert('I am Called');

  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert('I am Called From jQuery');
  });

}
```

Comment: I followed your solution and only your hardcoded library solution inside index.html works. I wonder why import is not working as you explained ?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery writes itself to window.$ or if you use jQuery.noConflict() it will appear in window.jQuery, so you can use $ or jQuery on a website. It do not export an object.

To use jQuery in your Angular-project, implement jQuery into your `scripts` section of you `./angular.json` for Angular 6 and 7 or in older projects (Angular 2 - 5) `./angular-cli.json`.

Search for `"scripts": []`

and replace it with

`"scripts": ["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]`

Then you have access to $ as jQuery in your code.

Comment: I added my Angular.json file in the question, this an auto-generated file by the Jhipster. I am not sure the way I added script file but still, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use jquery just to change theme? do not use it and live happily with just the css, bootstrap has ng-bootstrap in angular instead of jquery for bs widget, and the theme is just css. No more jquery required. Anyway jhipster themes are based on [bootswatch](https://bootswatch.com/) bs theme collection, [there](https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/009_tips_using_bootswatch_themes.html) is explained how you can change css theme with just one line. If more customization is needed, you can write your own css theme, it is not hard.